# Stolen bitcoins

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I started with buying bitcoins last week and I have been stolen twice. The first time I wasn't that sure if my cellphone was save so I downloaded authenticator for my second chance. I changed password and I followed every safety option on the wallet site blockchain. Yesterday it happened again. I don't know what to do. The weird thing was that I didn't get any mails or hacking signals. Ans it was a transaction to another wallet that I never confirmed, but it was already used money.
Could someone help me?

Comment: you may want to be a bit more specific, as this question is not clear enough. Which wallet, which cell phone, which provider, whch authenticator, where you bought bitcoins... there are so many options, that are unclear.

Comment: Okay I have a samsung galaxy s5 and it is about my online wallet on blockchain. The authenticator is an application in the appstore and thats already the name of it. My money has been stolen by an address from blockchain and I actually want to find the one behind it. The person who did this to me twice has this address 
13wahvu3FP8LK8P51UmEkhBUhyC7mzkrn3

Comment: First of all, let me say, that I feel sorry for the loss. So you have an online wallet with blockchain. There I can see 100s of tx with this address, many per day... Can you really be sure, that there are no issues with your cell phone? You didn't provide any tx ID or address, can you identify your address on this page, in these tx? Is the weblink you used correct? Is the authenticator downloaded from a verified source? This will be difficult to verify, and looks more like a software and/or exchange issue. If not done already, you might need to contact your provider, and go from there.

Comment: There is absolutly nothing wrong with my cellphone. I have my wallet on the original website. I didn't provide any address. And I absolutely didn't give promission for the tx. Could my provider be responsible then? What do you recommend me to do. Is there any option that I could get my money back? Thank you btw for trying to help me.

Comment: First focus on how you lost them. Deal with getting your bitcoins back later. What is the address that you had your bitcoins on?

Comment: 1NZ9rHrSQbtHM4nTPVVFKcJF5YPaMDyjtB this is the address now